# remove edges NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I've built a graph with the following details. What I am confused of is why after removing one of the edges of the graph, it still exists when I try to print the all the edge data?

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edge(17, 12, nm=5, asset="a12")
G.add_edge(14, 13, nm=15, asset="a13")
G.add_edge(17, 13, nm=5, asset="a14")
G.add_edge(27, 110, nm=15, asset="a15")
G.add_edge(27, 110, nm=5, asset="a19")
G.add_edge(27, 280, nm=5, asset="a19")

# remove asset a15
for a, b, attributes in G.edges(data=True):
    if attributes["asset"]=="a15": 
        lst=[(a, b)]
G.remove_edges_from(lst)

#print the current edges in the graph
for cc in nx.connected_components(G):
   print("asset", list(nx.get_edge_attributes(G.subgraph(cc), "asset").values()))
```

Output:

```
asset ['a12', 'a14', 'a13']
asset ['a19', 'a15']
```

Why is `'a15'` still present?

I also want to remove *all* edges with asset tag `'a15'`, if there are more than one.

Answer (score 1):

For a MultiGraph, [`remove_edges_from`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.MultiGraph.remove_edges_from.html#networkx.MultiGraph.remove_edges_from) (and [`remove_edge`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.MultiGraph.remove_edge.html#networkx.MultiGraph.remove_edge), which only removes a single edge) will remove the most recently added edge between the specified nodes, unless you tell it otherwise by supplying a key. Your code removes the edge labeled `'a19'` between `27` and `110`, because it was added after the one marked `'a15'`. (You still see `'a19'` in the printed output because you also gave that asset name to the edge between `27` and `280`.)

Additionally, if there are multiple edges labeled `'a15'`, you'll only ever remove one of them, because you don't *build* `lst` as you go, you just set it to a single pair of nodes each time you get a match.

You can get the key of the relevant node by supplying `keys=True` to the [`edges`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.MultiGraph.edges.html#networkx.MultiGraph.edges) method and build a list, like so:

```
to_remove = []
for a, b, key, attributes in G.edges(keys=True, data=True):
    if attributes["asset"] == "a15": 
        to_remove.append((a, b, key))
G.remove_edges_from(to_remove)
```

Depending on what you find more readable, this could be condensed to a [list comprehension](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/):

```
to_remove = [(a, b, key)
             for a, b, key, attributes in G.edges(keys=True, data=True)
             if attributes["asset"] == "a15"]
G.remove_edges_from(to_remove)
```

Or even:

```
G.remove_edges_from([
    (a, b, key)
    for a, b, key, attributes in G.edges(keys=True, data=True)
    if attributes["asset"] == "a15"
])
```

Notably, [`add_edge`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.MultiGraph.add_edge.html#networkx.MultiGraph.add_edge) also *returns* the key of the new edge, so you could potentially save them ahead of time, depending on your needs. These keys should remain unique *for any particular pair of nodes*.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I use the above code, but since I have multiple of asset that need to be removed, I got a RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration :/ . Is there a way to fix this one ?

Comment: @user20321911 Well that's an important detail. So just to clarify, there are / could be multiple edges with the same asset tag, and you want to remove all of them?

Comment: @user20321911 I've edited my answer (and your question) to reflect your added requirement as I understand it.